# How to detect human typing and prevent spamming on a chatting website

Tags: javascript, php, html

We have a chatting website and we disabled the Copy-Paste function to prevent spammers. But now they have found a new way to use auto typing software to spam. Is there any way to detect human typing or anything like that to stop them from spamming?

Comment: Upon login have a captcha to verify them?

Answer (score 6):

Detecting a robot versus a human typing would be a wasted effort of computing power. Perhaps to use the website you should use a captcha to determine if they are a robot. I would issue another captcha if they are:

1. sending messages too frequently
2. connecting with other patrons too frequently

This is what other popular chat websites do. Another way is to detect what their last message was, and not display it if it is the same as the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CAPTCHA to do this. A CAPTCHA is a type of test used to determine whether or not the user is human. There are various providers of this service which would allow you to avoid building on yourself. For example:

- Google recaptcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/
- captcha.net: http://www.captcha.net/

Comment: But they can pass the CAPTCHA test, bcoz they are connecting as a normal users, but once they are connected to server, they are using the AUTO TYPTER softwares to curse and spam,

I was thinking if its possible to set a spesefic typing speed to stop them, like if its typed fast the script detect as a spammer

Comment: Ah, that might be more difficult. If your problem is cursing and spamming, you could implement something that blacklists certain patterns so that posts containing that pattern are flagged as abuse. You might also be able to flag those users (or IP addresses) and limit their ability to send messages.